# Ramsey number for paths

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Let $n = R(P_{r+1}, c)$ be the smallest integer such that if $K_n$ is $c$-edge-coloured, then it contains a monochromatic subgraph isomorphic to $P_{r+1}$, the path of length $r$. I need to show that $R(P_{r+1}, c) \leq r^c + 1$.

I believe that the best known bound is linear in terms of $r$, so this is really rough, but I still can't get anywhere. I have tried modifying the usual proof of Ramsey's theorem, showing that $R(s, t) \leq R(s - 1, t) + R(s, t - 1)$ (Erdos-Szekeres), but to no avail. I have also tried proving the bound:
$$R(P_{r+1}, c) - 1\leq r(R(P_{r+1}, c - 1) - 1)$$
by partitioning a complete graph into a product of $r$ complete subgraphs. I do know know if this bounds holds, but if it did, I would get the desired answer.

Please help with hints, not complete solutions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We proceed by induction on $c$.

When $c = 1$, $R(P_{r + 1}, 1) \leq r + 1$, since $K_{r + 1}$ contains all possible edges between $r + 1$ vertices, and a path of length $r$ is one such choice.

Let $n = R(P_{r+1}, c)$, $G = K_n$. Let $G$ be $(c - 1)$-edge-coloured, and extend this to a $c$-edge-colouring of $H = K_{n + \lfloor r/2 \rfloor}$, where the new complete subgraph $K_{\lfloor r/2 \rfloor}$ is $1$-edge-coloured for a previous colour used in $G$, and all of the edges linking $G$ to this subgraph are $1$-edge-coloured in a new colour. This is a graph with no monochromatic path of length $r$, so:
$$R(P_{r+1}, c) \leq R(P_{r}, c - 1) + \lfloor r/2 \rfloor$$
So, by the induction hypothesis:
$$R(P_{r+1}, c) \leq r^{c-1} + 1 + \lfloor r/2 \rfloor \leq r^c + 1$$
And this last inequality is true since:
\begin{align*}
&r^{c-1} + 1 + \lfloor r/2 \rfloor \leq r^c + 1 \\
\iff &\lfloor r/2 \rfloor \leq r^{c-1}(r - 1)
\end{align*}
If $r$ is even, then $r \geq 2$ and:
$$\frac{1}{2} \leq r^{c - 2}(r - 1)$$
This last inequality might not hold if $c = 1$, but in that case:
$$\frac{1}{2} \leq 1 - \frac{1}{r}$$
and since $r \geq 2$, this is true.

If $r$ is odd, then $r \geq 1$ and:
$$\frac{r - 1}{2} \leq r^{c - 1}(r - 1) \iff \frac{1}{2} \leq r^{c - 1}$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: Isn't this the opposite inequality?

Answer (score 0):

You must prove the following claim:

> *Claim.* Let $r$ and $c$ be two nonnegative integers. Let $n$ be an integer such that $n > r^c$. Assume that the edges of the complete graph $K_n$ have been colored with $c$ colors. Then, $K_n$ has a monochromatic path of length $r$. (A path is called *monochromatic* if all its edges have the same color.)

*Proof.* Let $1, 2, \ldots, n$ be the vertices of $K_n$. Let $V$ be the set of all these $n$ vertices. A walk $\left(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_s\right)$ of $K_n$ will be called *increasing* if $v_1 < v_2 < \cdots < v_s$. Note that any increasing walk is a path.

Let $1, 2, \ldots, c$ be the $c$ colors. For each vertex $i \in V$ and each color $k \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,c\right\}$, let $f_{i,k}$ denote the maximum length of an increasing path starting at $i$ such that all edges of this path have color $k$. (This is well-defined, since the length-$0$ path $\left(i\right)$ always exists, and since a path in $K_n$ cannot have length $\geq n$.)

Now, let us assume (for contradiction) that $K_n$ has no monochromatic path of length $r$. Then, in particular, $K_n$ has no monochromatic increasing path of length $r$. Hence, any monochromatic increasing path has length $\leq r-1$. Therefore, $f_{i,k} \in \left\{0,1,\ldots,r-1\right\}$ for all $i$ and $k$. Now, for each $i \in V$, let $f_i$ be the $c$-tuple $\left(f_{i,1},f_{i,2},\ldots,f_{i,c}\right)$. This $c$-tuple belongs to the $r^c$-element set $\left\{0,1,\ldots,r-1\right\}^c$ (since $f_{i,k} \in \left\{0,1,\ldots,r-1\right\}$ for all $i$ and $k$). By the pigeonhole principle, we thus conclude that two of these $c$-tuples $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n$ are equal (since $n > r^c$). That is, there exist two vertices $v$ and $w$ such that $v < w$ and $f_v = f_w$. Consider these vertices $v$ and $w$. Now, let $k$ be the color of the edge $vw$, and observe that $f_v = f_w$ entails $f_{v,k} = f_{w,k}$.

Now, take a longest increasing path starting at $w$ whose edges all have color $k$. This path has length $f_{w,k}$ (by the definition of $f_{w,k}$). Let us now extend this path by inserting the vertex $v$ (and the edge $vw$) at its front. The result is a walk of length $f_{w,k}+1$ that starts at $v$ and has the property that all its edges have color $k$ (since the edge $vw$ has color $k$). This walk furthermore is increasing (since $v < w$), and thus is a path. Hence, we have found an increasing path of length $f_{w,k}+1$ that starts at $v$ and has the property that all its edges have color $k$. Therefore, $f_{v,k} \geq f_{w,k}+1 > f_{w,k}$, which contradicts $f_{v,k} = f_{w,k}$. This shows that our assumption was false, and thus the claim is proved.

**Remark.** This can be generalized: If $D$ is a [tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)) with more than $r^c$ vertices, and if the arcs of $D$ are colored with $c$ colors, then $D$ has a monochromatic path of length $r$. This is a particular case of Theorem 2 in [Yannis Manoussakis, Zsolt Tuza, *Ramsey numbers for tournaments*, Theoretical Computer Science **263**, Issues 1--2, 28 July 2001, Pages 75--85](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0304-3975(00)00232-2). The proof in the general case is more complicated. Note that this general result also generalizes Redei's little theorem, which says that every tournament has a Hamiltonian path. (Just take $c = 1$ to recover this.)